# Values from helper.js controller not passed to apex controller!

Tags: apex, lightning

I am trying to pass values from helper.js file to apex controller class. The apex controller dont seem to be getting the values. Here in this code I am passing the bStreet & bCity values.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountsActiveListApexController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<!--<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAccounts}" /> -->   
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>

<lightning:card>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-around_medium">

        <div class="slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">                        
            <div>
                <table class="slds-p-around_large bgSettings">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-p-around_small">
                                    <lightning:input aura:id="bStreet" placeholder="Street Name"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div class="slds-p-around_small slds-p-left_xx-small">
                                    <lightning:input aura:id="bCity" placeholder="City"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.searchAddress}">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-float_right slds-p-right_medium">
                                    <lightning:buttonGroup>
                                        <lightning:button label="Never" class="slds-button_neutral" value="never"/>
                                        <lightning:button label="Cold" class="slds-button_neutral" value="cold"/>
                                        <lightning:button label="Active" class="slds-button_neutral" value="active"/>
                                        <lightning:button label="X" class="slds-button_neutral" value="clear"/>
                                    </lightning:buttonGroup>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>    
                </table>
                <table id="oppsTable" class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-p-around_x-small">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="slds-text-title_caps tableColumnHeader">
                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate" title="Account Number">Account Number</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-text-title_caps tableColumnHeader">
                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-text-title_caps tableColumnHeader">
                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate" title="Billing Address">Billing Address</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-text-title_caps tableColumnHeader">
                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-text-heading_x-small slds-align_absolute-center">{! acc.AccountNumber }</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-text-heading_x-small slds-align_absolute-center">{! acc.Name }</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-text-heading_x-small slds-align_absolute-center">{! acc.sumchans__Address__c}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-text-heading_x-small slds-align_absolute-center">{! acc.sumchans__Status__c }</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

Helper .js:

```
    searchAddresses : function(component, bStreet, bCity) {  
    var address = component.get("c.accountsOnAddress");
    address.setParams(
        {
            bStreet : bStreet,
            bCity : bCity
        }
    );   
    //console.log(bStreet, bCity);
    address.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();           
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }            
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(address); 
}
```

Apex Controller Code:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> accountsOnAddress(String bStreet, String bCity) {
    System.debug('Test');
    return [Select AccountNumber, Name, sumchans__Address__c, sumchans__Status__c From Account Where BillingCity='bCity'];           
}
```

Comment: can you add the component as well, please?

Comment: @Carlos Original post edited with component.

Comment: fyi: naming your variables the same as your attributes is never a good idea, in such a case, you might want to consider converting your attribute names to strings, ex: "bStreet" : bStreet and "bCity": bCity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you can just bind your inputs to an attribute. This makes your code easier to read. Here's one way I might do this:

```
<aura:attribute name="filters" type="Map" default="{ 'bCity': '', 'bStreet': '' }" />
```

...

```
<lightning:input label="Street" value="{!v.filters.bStreet}" />
```

...

```
<lightning:input label="City" value="{!v.filters.bCity}" />
```

...

Which makes your search function look like this:

```
searchAddresses: function(component) {
  var action = component.get("c.accountsOnAddress");
  action.setParams(component.get("v.filters"));
  action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
    var state = result.getState();
    if(state === "SUCCESS") {
      component.set("v.accounts", component.getReturnValue());
    } else {
      // deal with errors here
    }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

---

As an aside, your Apex Code is also wrong; you're searching for the literal term 'bCity', not the variable. You'll need to use variable binding:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> accountsOnAddress(String bStreet, String bCity) {
  return [Select AccountNumber, Name, sumchans__Address__c, sumchans__Status__c From Account Where BillingCity=:bCity];
}
```

Comment: Whoa! I did not know lightning automatically converts a clientside map attribute into it's appropriate serverside parameter mapping without explicitly setting them... But this makes perfect sense once I saw it. I would venture this works if you pass an object in (directly) and let the properties be the apex params?

Comment: @tsalb Yes, that also works as well. The framework just expects an object that has key-value pairs, it doesn't really matter how you get there. I just think this format happens to be a bit easier to read.

Comment: The other day I had trouble finding a good place to "declare" what keys are possible on my objects so I will be borrowing this....thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is any particular reason why you are doing `searchAddress: function(component, bStreet, bCity)` ? 
Change that for `searchAddress: function(component, event, helper)`.

You probably need to get **bStreet** and **bCity** from the component before passing it to your Apex class. There are no values for those fields? You may want to set the "value" attribute. After that, you can get that value and pass it to the Apex method.

I think if you change those lines to these:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="bStreet" placeholder="Street Name" value=""/>
```

and

```
<lightning:input aura:id="bStreet" placeholder="Street Name" value=""/>
```

You will be capturing the values entered by the user.

```
var bStreet = component.find("v.bStreet").get("v.value");
var bCity = component.find("v.bCity").get("value");
```

Please, try this:

```
searchAddresses : function(component, event, helper) {  
    var bStreet = component.find("v.bStreet").get("v.value");
    var bCity = component.find("v.bCity").get("v.value");

    var address = component.get("c.accountsOnAddress");
    address.setParams({
            bStreet : bStreet,
            bCity : bCity
        });
```

I think that the problem is that you are passing nothing to your Apex method. Try this approach and let us know if it works.

**UPDATE** -- *setCallback*

As I mentioned, you need to set the results coming from your setCallback.

```
 address.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();           
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
```

You need set the results doing something like this:

```
address.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();           
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            component.set("v.accounts",result);
            //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
```

You are getting the `reponse.getReturnValue` and you are assigning that to the `result` variable. Then I assume that you want to pass those values to your:

```
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>
```

So that is what you should try....

In Apex you use:

> system.debug();

for

> console.log()

Comment: That is the exactly the way I have it now, the only thing is I added the value attribute to the lightning:input component. It still doesn't work. How do I do the console.log in the apex controller class?

Comment: In your setCallback, there is no logic to set back to the component the results coming from that callback.